# Decoding mimemultimessage from bytearray returns junk

Tags: jakarta-mail

I have to make a configurable email template where I am trying to store a `MimeMultiMessage` as byte array in DB. :-

```
    private byte[]encodeMsg(MimeMultipart multipart) {
    try 
    {
         ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
         multipart.writeTo(baos);
         return baos.toByteArray();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And my decoder is :-

```
    private MimeMultipart decodeMsg(byte[] byteArray) {
    MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
    DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(byteArray, "multipart/mixed");
    MimeBodyPart body = new MimeBodyPart();
    DataHandler dh = new DataHandler(ds);
    try {
        body.addHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/mixed");
        body.setDataHandler(dh);
        multipart.addBodyPart(body);
    } catch (MessagingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return multipart;
}
```

In the mail there is supposed to be three image attachments, which is working if I don't go through encode/decode. 
But by going through encode/decode I am getting a attachment named noname with junk (like a class as seen in notepad) inside it.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with storing the *content* of a MimeMultipart is that you also need to store the metadata from the corresponding MIME header, in particular the multipart subtype and the boundary value that lets you make sense of the content.  It's much better to store an entire MimeMessage, which will include all the MIME headers that allow the content to be parsed correctly.

Assuming you really want to store the multipart content, and that you've also stored the original Content-Type value for the multipart, you need to do something like the following:

```
DataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(byteArray, savedContentType);
MimeMultipart multipart = new MimeMultipart(ds);
return multipart;
```

That assumes byteArray contains the MIME format content for the multipart and
savedContentType is the entire Content-Type header value, including the boundary parameter.

Comment: Thanks for response. Now I have saved the content type of multipart before encoding . Now instead of one crude attachment I am getting 3 attachments as are the number of images in the original multipart. But still all 3 comes with name `noname` and all are corrupted

Comment: Need more details.  What exactly are you saving and what's in the byte array when you restore it?

Comment: I solved that, thanks but now I am facing another weird [problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49894767/images-received-as-attachments-rather-than-inline-as-desired). If you could be kind enough to have a look there, many thanks